# Max spiral / curve length inside circle which can cross any radius once

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a circle with radius length r, what is the maximum length of a curve which starts at the center and can cross any radius at most once? the curve must be contained inside the circle.

I would intuitively assume it is some kind of spiral, but honestly I don't even know if that question makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a limit without further constraints

For example consider a curve like this

[image]

and with more petals the blue curve could be made arbitrarily long

Comment: brilliant. of course. Thanks!